# Неполучается перенести из черного окна на форму c++

Tags: c++, c++-cli

задача состояло в том: нужно было поменять местами слова. на Console все получилось

я попытался перенести на форму 
когда хотел вывести на другом textbox ответ то пишет 
expression must a class type

```
for(int k = 0; k < j; k++)
{
 textBox2->Text=*(str1+k).ToString()+" ";
}
```

вот что у меня на форм с++

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, 
System::EventArgs^  e) {
             system("chcp 1251");
int i=Convert::ToInt32(textBox3->Text);
int l=Convert::ToInt32(textBox4->Text);
char str[len];
char *str1[len];
label1->Text="Введите строку:";
label2->Text="Ответ : ";
for(int i=0;i<textBox1->Text->Length;i++)
{
    str[i]=textBox1->Text[i];
}
int j = 0;
str1[j] = strtok(str,leks); //в указатель str1[0] заносится первое слово (лексема)
while(str1[j] != NULL)   //когда слова закончатся то функция возвращает NULL, поэтому пока указатель не NULL, делаем
{
    j++;
    str1[j] = strtok(NULL, leks);//заносим очередную лексему в указатель, у нас это массив
}

i--;  //уменьшаем, т.к. массив идет с нуля

l--;  //уменьшаем т.к. массив с нуля
 swap(str1[i],str1[l]);//меняем местами
for(int k = 0; k < j; k++)
{
 textBox2->Text=*(str1+k).ToString()+" ";//это как вывод одномерных массивов, можно str1[k]
}
         }
};
```

}

Comment: как исправить ошибку expression must have a class type

Comment: все остальное вроде без ошибок

Comment: Решил проблему сам